# Contour plotting multiple curves

Tags: plotting

I am wondering why the following does not work:

```
eqns = Table[x + n y == n, {n, 1, 3}]  
ContourPlot[eqns, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 2}]
```

However, if I copy the output of 'eqns' and paste in directly to the contour plot function, I do get the contour plot:

`ContourPlot[{x + y == 1, x + 2 y == 2, x + 3 y == 3}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 2}]` 
 
To me they are one and the same.

Comment: Works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eoARJ.png (Mathematica 10.1)

Comment: Works fine with 10.3.1 on Win 8.1 Pro 64bit

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget `Evaluate`!

```
eqns = Table[x + n y == n, {n, 1, 3}]
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqns, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I can't up your points yet.

Comment: @PMay. Yes you can. You can't up-vote, but you can award 15 reputation points by accepting the answer. Click on the check-mark just below the down arrow on the left of the answer.